# Misma funcion para eventos diferentes de diferentes elementos. jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo varios elementos HTML que quiero que ejecuten la misma funcion, en diferentes eventos tipo mouseover, clic, etc.

No quería repetir el mismo código para cada uno de los elementos. Ejemplo: aquí aplico en el evento change de un select, pero quiero aplicar para el evento mouseover de un botón, y el clic de un link, que van a hacer todo esto mismo. ¿Tengo que copiar todo el código nuevamente? No tengo como llamar a este mismo código sin tenerlo repetido.

```
$('select[name=confirm]').change(function() {
  entradav =  $('input[name=fechaent]').val();
  salidav =   $('input[name=fechasal]').val();
  quartov =   $('select[name=quartos]').val();
  idv =       $('input[name=id]').val();           

  $("#modal-footer").delay(1000).queue(function(n) {      

  $("#modal-footer").html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader_blue.gif" />');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "compruevaover.php",
    data: 'entrada=' + entradav + '&salida=' + salidav + '&quarto=' + quartov + '&id=' + idv,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){
          alert("error petición ajax");
    },
    success: function(data){                                                      
          $("#modal-footer").html(data);
          n();
    }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando on(), esto captura múltiples eventos:

```
$('#element, #element2').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
    // e.type este es el tipo de evento que ejecuta.
});
```

O puedes solo llamandola por una función

```
$('select[name=confirm]').change(function() {
    evento();
})

$('select[name=confirm]').click(function() {
    evento();
})

 function evento(){
//Lo que quieres hacer
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Fuente

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function

Answer (score 2):

Sí puedes, para eso tienes que usar una función.

```
function hola() {
  alert('Hola');
}

$('.elemento').click(function() {
  hola();
});

$('.menu').click(function() {
  hola();
});
```

En este ejemplo declaro una función llamada `hola`. La cual ejecuta una alerta. Esta función, la cual ejecuta un bloque de código, necesito ejecutarla en diferentes escenarios, como darle click a diferentes elementos, hacerle hover a otro elementos, etc. Para poder ejecutar mi función necesito llamarla con `hola();`. Esa instrucción indica que se va a ejecutar el bloque de código que está en la función `hola`.

En tu escenario necesitas meter todo el código que necesitas ejecutar dentro de una función y mandarla a llamar en los diferentes eventos en lo que lo necesites.

Answer (score 1):

Primero creamos una función llamada `RealizarAccion()`

```
function RealizarAccion()
{
    entradav =  $('input[name=fechaent]').val();
      salidav =   $('input[name=fechasal]').val();
      quartov =   $('select[name=quartos]').val();
      idv =       $('input[name=id]').val();           

      $("#modal-footer").delay(1000).queue(function(n) {      

      $("#modal-footer").html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader_blue.gif" />');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "compruevaover.php",
        data: 'entrada=' + entradav + '&salida=' + salidav + '&quarto=' + quartov + '&id=' + idv,
        dataType: "html",
        error: function(){
              alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(data){                                                      
              $("#modal-footer").html(data);
              n();
        }
      }); 
}
```

luego invocamos a esta función en nuestros eventos

```
$('#boton').click(function() {
  RealizarAccion();
});
```

o

```
$('select[name=confirm]').change(function() {
  RealizarAccion();
}
```

Espero esto te ayude, Saludos.

Comment: Súper, ayer segui buscando y encontre la misma sugerencia, ahi lo hice y funcionó, pero te agradezco un mundo. Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Gracias.

Comment: Que bueno, me encantaría que lo marcaras como respuesta correcta :)